# What is this spacetime metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

Does anyone know whether this metric has been studied before or if it has a proper name?

$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + e^{2At} dx^2 + e^{2Bt} dy^2 + e^{2Ct} dz^2$$

i.e. a de Sitter metric which has a different expansion rate in different directions. Or even the more general

$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + a^2(t) dx^2 + b^2(t) dy^2 +c^2(t)dz^2$$

I cannot find any papers/textbooks that mention either of these metrics.

Comment: I think they're reasonably well known: these are Bianchi I metrics, unless I'm very wrong. They don't seem to be very popular since one of the basic postulates (at least in cosmology) is that we live in a homogeneous and isotropic universe, but there have been some studies [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.07427.pdf), and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960187905950), for example.

Comment: @Philip-Cherian ; Sounds like an answer (or the germ of one).  Also this page on [Bianchi Universes](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bianchi_universes) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Such metrics describe what are known as **Bianchi I** universes after Luigi Bianchi who classified 3 dimensional Lie Algebras into eleven classes and showed that every such algebra is isomorphic to one and only one Lie Algebra on this list.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_classification) gives a brief summary of the classification, while - as @StephenG suggested - the [Scholarpedia page](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bianchi_universes) is a little more thorough.

As can be clearly seen from the metric, Bianchi I spaces are in general anisotropic and thus not very good candidates to describe the universe (at least in cosmology), since the universe has been observed to be isotropic to great precision. Nevertheless, they have been studied - in particular, the [Kasner metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasner_metric), which describes for example [anisotropic inflation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.07427.pdf).

Other mentions of such metrics can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9811086.pdf) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960187905950).